# Нужно сделать нейросеть, определяющую героя текста

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Мне необходимо сделать нейросеть, которая будет распознавать главного героя произведения.
С чего мне стоит начать? С какими материалами ознакомиться?
Я только недавно приступил к изучению машинного обучения и т.д.

Comment: Какие входные данные? Часть произведения или свободный пересказ произведения или название произведения.

Comment: Сами тексты, Игра престолов например, или Властелин колец.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про [`NLP`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0) и в частности про [`NER`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition). Скорее всего вам нужно будет выделить имена в тексте, а потом смотреть разные статистики. Возможно, имя гг будет самым упоминаемым в тексте (а возможно и нет). Может оно чаще всего будет упоминаться в предложениях вместе именами других персонажей. Может ещё что-то будет, это надо по конкретному тексту смотреть и думать. Самым упоминаемым в тексте может вообще оказаться название местности, а если произведение фантастическое, то вам будет не просто отделить название местности от названий персонажей. Хотя скорее всего по *векторам слов* это можно будет сделать - в каком контексте встречаются какие слова. Так что в сторону [`Word2Vec`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec) вам тоже нужно посмотреть.

А нейросети - это только один из инструментов, прежде чем начинать заниматься нейросетями вам хорошо бы какие-то базовые вещи про обработку текстов почитать.

Comment: отличный ответ было очень интересно

Comment: @timob256 Ну это очень-очень схематично )  Тема глубокая, там копать и копать

Comment: В теме курсовой - нейросети) Так что без них не обойтись. Я просто не совсем понимаю, на каком этапе анализа они могут быть применены. На этапе NER, когда необходимо соотносить имена героев с их вариациями, например Harry Potter - Harry - Potter?